# Why sqlite3_step is returning value 1000

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am binding the parameters and sending to sqlite3_step function , the pointer NULL check is there but the return value is 1000 , i am not getting why only few times this issue is coming .

Comment: Show your code. Especially since 1000 is not a [sqlite result code](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html) that the function can return.

Comment: And only tag the language you're actually using  - C++ and Objective C are two different things.

Comment: Hi Shawn i am using C++ in xcode .

Comment: please show a [mre]